How to reach an element created with JavaScript while scrapping via puppeteer?
I am using Puppeteer to reach a button (unfollow button) in my GitHub followings page. Because this button does not exist when I scrape this page I think it has been created by user-side JS code. Then I used waitForSelector command in order to wait for this button, but again page could not find the button. Here is my code:
const test2=async()=>{
    let url='https://github.com/nariman?tab=following'
    await browserInit()
    await page.goto(url)
    await page.waitForSelector('input.btn')
    console.log('done')
}


and it will cause this error:
TimeoutError: Waiting for selector `input.btn` failed: Waiting failed: 30000ms exceeded

You can test it in your own GitHub page. Is there any solution?

You don't seem to authenticate anywhere - I can't visit that page and unfollow people on your behalf, so neither can Puppeteer.

@jonrsharpe i just changed my name here for public question. everything is ok im my system but input not appear in scraped code

@trincot if you check unfollow buttons in github followings page (in browser inspect) those are inputs with .btn class.

You're right. I was looking at the follow buttons.

The point Jon was making is the pupeteer driven browser window does not get all your sessions from the browser you are using normally as your day to day. In fact, by design, it is completely isolated and on a different browser profile. The problem is simply because the pupeteer browser is not logged into github. And the unfollow button will appear only to authenticated users who already followed. The pupeteer code needs to go through the whole github logon flow. It doesnt do this for free, and doesn't care you are logged onto github in your "normal" chrome instance you are using.

@adsy completely right. Your answer helped me alot and my problem solved. Thanks alot :)

you can use something called MutationObserver like page.on('mutationover',callback) by using which you can monitor DOM changes and wait specifically for the unfollow button insertion
